# .jsdiff -- How to keep from duplicating HTML closing tag?

Tags: javascript, html, string-comparison

I'm building a text editor and wanted to have 3 versions at 1 time going.

The last version shows the difference (using .jsdiff) and comparing the two strings.

The problem is, if I even get close to the end, it shows the closing tag of whatever element I'm editing. That's no bueno.

[image]

Any idea how I can keep this from happening and just have pretty clean text?

`added`

**[Fiddle containing all necessary coding](http://jsfiddle.net/SL5NM/)**

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to be able to help you, such as what editor plugin you're using and the source code which is causing the problem.

Comment: jsdiff compares the two strings. http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Comment: OK, but from whence do the strings come? Without some idea of how you are producing the strings to be compared, it is impossible to tell you why the tags are appearing.

Comment: The strings are HTML pages, comparing the original and current, then rendering the difference in the 3rd instance. The code is `jsdiff'. I couldn't find a way to prevent this, and just wondered if there was a way to modify this code or maybe someone would know of a more appropriate script with a similar license.

Comment: @RobRaisch added fiddle to demonstrate problem.